# Pattern matching on Type in Idris

Tags: pattern-matching, idris, typecase

Probably it's elementary but I don't understand why the following function answers 1 for **fnc Nat** and also, for **fnc Integer**, which is not even included as a pattern.

```
fnc : Type -> Integer
fnc Bool = 1
fnc Nat = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pattern match on type and you shouldn't. When I compile your code I receive next error:

```
warning - Unreachable case: fnc Nat
```

This was already discussed earlier:

1. [Old discussion.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/idris-lang/L8cyD9YkSRU/lnzNppxxhhsJ)
2. [Some similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553856/how-to-compare-types-for-equality)
3. [Some similar issue on GitHub.](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/2075)

**UPDATE:**

Finally found more relevant question with answer:

[Why is typecase a bad thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220884/why-is-typecase-a-bad-thing)

Comment: @Shersh Thanks for the last link! Could you vote for reopening this perfectly good question? I think it's a shame it has been closed.

Comment: @AntonTrunov I also think so. Voted for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

You can in fact now do this in Idris 2:

```
fnc : Type -> Integer
fnc Bool = 1
fnc Nat = 2
fnc _ = 3
```